# Sort aggregated array by array indices from other collection (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb

### Conditions

I have two collections with the following schemas (simplified).

**1st collection**:

```
{
  elements: [
    { identifier: 'b' },
    { identifier: 'a' },
    { identifier: 'c' }
  ]
}
```

**2nd collection**:

```
{
  index: 1,
  identifier: 'a',
  value: 5
}
```

### Target

I'd like to aggregate the 2nd one by index and make sure that the `identifier`s is in the same order as the 1st one.

**Example output**:

```
[{
  index: 1,
  elements: [
    { identifier: 'b', value: 5 },
    { identifier: 'a', value: 3 },
    { identifier: 'c', value: 6 }
  ]
}, {
  index: 2,
  elements: [
    { identifier: 'b', value: 1 },
    { identifier: 'a', value: 2 },
    { identifier: 'c', value: 9 }
  ]
}, {
  index: 3,
  elements: [
    { identifier: 'b', value: 3 },
    { identifier: 'a', value: 6 },
    { identifier: 'c', value: 4 }
  ]
}]
```

Please notice that the `identifier`s are always in the same order as given at the 1st collection.

### What I have

This is what I got:

```
[
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$index",
      "elements": {
        "$push": {
          "value": "$value",
          "identifier": "$identifier"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "index": "$_id",
      "elements": 1
    }
  }
]
```

It gives me the correct result only when the documents are inserted by the 1st collections `identifier` order. But insertion order not guaranteed.

### Sample data

#### 1st collection

```
{
  elements: [
    { identifier: 'b' },
    { identifier: 'a' },
    { identifier: 'c' }
  ]
}
```

#### 2nd collection

```
[{
  index: 1,
  identifier: 'a',
  value: 5
}, {
  index: 1,
  identifier: 'b',
  value: 3
}, {
  index: 1,
  identifier: 'c',
  value: 6
}, {
  index: 2,
  identifier: 'a',
  value: 1
}, {
  index: 2,
  identifier: 'b',
  value: 2
}, {
  index: 2,
  identifier: 'c',
  value: 9
}, {
  index: 3,
  identifier: 'a',
  value: 3
}, {
  index: 3,
  identifier: 'b',
  value: 6
}, {
  index: 3,
  identifier: 'c',
  value: 4
}]
```

Comment: Can your above sample collections produce the expected output? If not the pls update your question and show reproducible sample data.

Comment: I added sample data to produce the "Example output".

Comment: The Aggregate query shown here to get the desired output uses only  `2nd collection` you are not using your `1st collection` in the query. Use `$lookup` to sync both collections and get your output data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the existing schema of `1st collection` we will not be able to achieve the desired result, but we can modify the `1st collection` by adding an attribute which would help us in doing the custom sort.

After adding the new attribute which helps us in sorting the `1st collection` will look like

```
{
  "_id": "5d1b72ab1031330010d8602c",
  "elements": [
    {
      "identifier": "b", "order": 1
    },
    {
      "identifier": "a",  "order": 2
    },
    {
      "identifier": "c",  "order": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Then the below query will bring us the desired result

```
db.2ndcollection.aggregate([
  { "$lookup" : { from : "1stcollection", localField: "identifier", foreignField:"elements.identifier", as:"newb" }},
  {$unwind: "$newb"},
  {$unwind: "$newb.elements"}, 
  {$project: { "identifier":1, "index":1, "value":1, 
               "newb.elements.identifier":1, "newb.elements.order":1, 
                flag : { $cond : { 
                        if : { $eq : [ "$identifier", "$newb.elements.identifier"] }, then : 1, else: 0 } }
              }
  },
  { $match: { flag : 1 } },
  { $sort : { "newb.elements.order" : 1} },
  { $group : {
      "_id": "$index", 
      "elements": { "$push": { "value": "$value", "identifier": "$identifier" } }
    }
  }
 ]);
```

Aggregation Pipeline stages used to achieve the result are

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) - To merge the two collections

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) - To unwind the array

[$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) - Project the required attributes to the next stage

[$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) - Filter out the matching items

[$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) - Sort the items

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) - Group the items